# Replace special characters in string

Tags: ruby, string, special-characters

I have strings like

- `"Ruby & Rails"`
- `"Ruby& Rails"`
- `"Ruby !Rails"`

I want to convert them to `"Ruby-Rails"`. How can I do this?

Comment: did you want to remove `1`, `2`?

Comment: No. I want to convert strings like 1,2,3 to Ruby-Rails. They all are different versions which have special characters.

Comment: is 1,2,3 actually present on your input string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming 1,2,3 are serial number for example and not are actually present in String, you can use `split` and `join`:

```
a = "Ruby & Rails"
a.split(/\W+/).join("-")
# => "Ruby-Rails"

"Ruby& Rails".split(/\W+/).join("-")
# => "Ruby-Rails"

"Ruby !Rails".split(/\W+/).join("-")
# => "Ruby-Rails"
```

Alternatively if serial number is also part of input string:

```
"1. Ruby& Rails".split(/\W+|\d+/).reject(&:empty?).join("-")
# => "Ruby-Rails"

"2. Ruby& Rails".split(/\W+|\d+/).reject(&:empty?).join("-")
# => "Ruby-Rails"

"3. Ruby !Rails".split(/\W+|\d+/).reject(&:empty?).join("-")
# => "Ruby-Rails"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
" Ruby ! Rails ".split(/\W+/).reject(&:empty?).join("-")
=> "Ruby-Rails"
```

Comment: I will need to provide all the special characters in the split? Is there a way to give some regex?

Comment: yes,  `\W`:  Any non-word character

Answer (score 0):

You could use gsub.

```
string.gsub(/\s*\W+\s*/, "-")
```

OR

```
string.gsub(/\W+/, "-")
```